# Constraint is invalid: there is no unique or primary key constraint on table that matches the number and types of the columns in the foreign key

Tags: java, spring, derby

I'm trying to create 2 tables with reference. But I can't find my mistake.
This is script for derby:

```
CREATE TABLE AUDITORIUM (
  audId BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  nameAud          VARCHAR(50),
  numberOfSeats    INTEGER,
  vipSeats         VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE EVENT (
  eventId    BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  name       VARCHAR(50),
  basePrice  INTEGER,
  rating     VARCHAR(50),
  audId      BIGINT,
FOREIGN KEY (audId) REFERENCES AUDITORIUM (audId)
);
```

As a result I am getting this error:
Constraint 'SQL160511200811240' is invalid: there is no unique or primary key constraint on table '"SA"."AUDITORIUM"' that matches the number and types of the columns in the foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that the `audId` column in the `AUDITORIUM` table needs to be declared as the `PRIMARY KEY` (or UNIQUE). Foreign keys can only reference unique or primary keys in another table.